# What is the equivalent function for pixelgrabber (Java) in C#

Tags: c#, java, image-processing

I want to grab all pixel values of a Bitmap image in C# and push it into a two-dimensional array. In Java, it's easy to do with the pixelgrabber function.

What is the equivalent function to pixelgrabber (Java) in C#?

Comment: In C# you have the [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx) method, so just loop over the width and height (nested loop) and populate the array. If you're struggling let me know and I'll try to come with some sample code.

Comment: yap , i understood your ideas . Thanks you:)

Comment: Tim gave proper code, for small images (I'd say up to 100x100) it can be ideal as it's managed code, for larger images use the unsafe way.

Answer (score 3):

It's `GetPixel`.

```
BitmapImage image;
image.GetPixel (0, 0);
```

This will work, but it's not meant for parsing the whole image (it might be slow). You need to get into unmanaged code and get a pointer to the raw data if you want the performance. A sample is in *[Using the LockBits method to access image data](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx)*.